# How can i insert DateTime in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

how can i insert this DateTime in SQL?

1/21/2020 8:30:53.527000 AM +00:00

I know that for 12/12/2020  we can make TO_DATE('12/12/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, in your `INSERT` statement you can use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```sql
TIMESTAMP '2020-01-21 08:30:53.527000 +00:00'
```

Or use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`:

```sql
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
  '1/21/2020 8:30:53.527000 AM +00:00',
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF6 AM TZH:TZM'
)
```